# Delete file after successful upload to S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload a file to S3 and then delete it when upload succeeds. I am using TransferUtility as

```
for(final File p:photos){
        String key = getKey(p.getName());
        TransferObserver observer = getTransferUtility().upload(S3_BUCKET,key,p);
        observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                if(TransferState.COMPLETED == state){
                    p.delete();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Since upload is asynchronous, the call to `onStateChanged` is bound to be out of phase with the for-loop. So how do I make sure the correct file is deleted each time?

**Update**

One approach that could work is if I could grab the correct `observer` from inside `onStateChanged`. Then I could do

```
@Override
public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
  if(TransferState.COMPLETED == state){
    Observer obs = getParentObserver();//similar to a Fragment's getActivity() or getContext()
    File file = new File(obs.getAbsoluteFilePath());
    file.delete();
  }
}
```

Notice that the following won't work as the `id`s will likely never match

```
@Override
public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
  if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) {
    if (observer.getId() == id) {
      String filePath = observer.getAbsoluteFilePath();
      File file = new File(observer.getAbsoluteFilePath());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am intrigued to find out why you would like to delete the file as soon as it is uploaded, maybe the answer will be different then.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the transfer by id.

```
String path = getTransferUtility().getTransferById(id).getAbsoluteFilePath();
new File(path).delete();
getTransferUtility().delete(id);
```